# Countable and Uncountable subsets of $\mathcal{P(\mathbb{Z})}$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

Suppose I have a relation on $\mathcal{P(\mathbb{Z})}$ which says give me all ordered tuples $(S,T)\in\mathcal{P(\mathbb{Z})} \times \mathcal{P(\mathbb{Z})}$ such that $S\underset{\text{bijection}}{\longrightarrow}T$. Now this is obviously an equivalence relation and then consider now the equivalence classes of $[{0}]$ and $[\mathbb{Z}]$. The question is that does $[\mathbb{Z}]$ have the same cardinality as $\mathbb{Z}$ my intution says no.  $[\mathbb{Z}]$ is a infinite set of infinitely countable subsets of $\mathbb{Z}$. But the set itself $[\mathbb{Z}]$ seems to be an infinte subset of the $\mathcal{P(\mathbb{Z})}$ which we know is uncountable. On the other hand of inquiries, is the $[\{0\}]$ numerically equivalent to the set $[\{0,1,2,3,...k\}]$ where $k\in\mathbb{N}$, clearly they have the same cardinality since the class $[\{0,1,2,3,...k\}]$ contains all sets which have cardinality $\vert k+1\vert$. How would I go about proving that?

Comment: There are countably many finite subsets of $\mathbb Z$; thus, there are uncountably many infinite ones, and each of these is in $[\mathbb Z]$.

Comment: What do you mean with $[\{0\}]$ being numerically equivalent to $[\{0,1,\dots,k\}]$? Given the context, do you claim that $\{0\}$ has the same cardinal as $\{0,1,\dots,k\}$? That doesn't seem right.

Comment: No of course I dont claim that, I dont really understand where the confusion is coming from, I am comparing the cardinality of equivalence classes of the relation R, I am not at all comparing the sets containing just zero and the set containing non-negative integers up to k. That does not make sense at all.

Comment: Ok, I got it now. Maybe it was clear enough, my bad.

Comment: As for the first comment, you need to be more concrete!

Comment: What is the part that you find unclear? Some claim or its relevance?

Comment: My goal with that comment is to show that $[\mathbb Z]$ is uncountable.

Comment: OP, perhaps you could say a little more about what you know about cardinality and what facts you're allowed to quote? amrsa's first comment is exactly the right argument, but perhaps it assumes more background than what you have. There are many ways to prove this, both elementary and not so elementary. Do you agree that what you're trying to prove is "there are uncountably many countably infinite subsets of $\Bbb Z$"? Do you see why you could replace $\Bbb Z$ with $\Bbb N$ or $\Bbb Q$? With $\Bbb N$ you can do a diagonal argument, and with $\Bbb Q$ you can do a clever trick (Dedekind cuts..)

Comment: Could you explain how the argument there countably many finite subsets of Z implies there are therefore are uncountably many infinite ones. What I actually meant to say is could you rephrase your argument in another perspective so possibly or even show some math or theorems to assert this claim.

Comment: That fact used the following: "if $X$ is an uncountable set and $Y \subseteq X$ is countable, then $X \setminus Y$ (the set of elements of $X$ not in $Y$) is uncountable." You can prove this as follows: "if $X \setminus Y$ was countable, then $X = (X \setminus Y) \cup Y$ is a union of two countable sets, and is hence countable, which contradicts the assumption that $X$ is uncountable".

Comment: Ok i see thanks, sorry if I came off rather abrupt.

Comment: Your post refers to both $[0]$ and $[\{0\}]$. The first, presumably, is a typographical error?

Answer (score 1):

Consider $A=2\mathbb{Z}$, i.e. the subset of all numbers divisible by $2$ and its complement $B$. Both are countable. Moreover for any subset $C\subseteq B$ we have that $A\cup C$ is countable. And then the function $C\mapsto A\cup C$, as a function $P(B)\to P(\mathbb{Z})$ is injective. Meaning there is uncountably many countable subsets of $\mathbb{Z}$.

On the other hand there is countably many finite subsets of $\mathbb{Z}$. That's because every finite subset is a subset of some $\{-n,\ldots,-1,0,1,\ldots,n\}$ and each such subset has finitely many subsets itself. This easily implies that each $[X]$ is countable for finite $X$.